# How should personally identifiable information be stored in incognito pools for multi-region support discussion

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

To be compliant with some rules, we need to store PII in the same region as the customer is located. I believe PII will be stored incognito so what's the recommended way to do it? Should we create and manage a user pool in different regions for ex:

```
userpool-users-us

userpool-users-eu

userpool-users-ap
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Some of the PII will also be stored in DynamoDB. Should we only store authentication information in Cognito and the rest of the PII in the dynamodb instead?

If I was to store this in DynamoDB,

How should this be accomplished keeping in mind that the customers are spread across continents i.e Asia, US, EU e.t.c (so If I was to use global tables and replicate data in multiple regions, how should that be done in DynamoDB).